# How to use draftwatermark to apply watermark only to selected pages?

Tags: draftwatermark

So on the documentation for draftwatermark, the author claims that: The draftwatermark package extends LATEX providing a means to add a watermark (typically textual and light gray, but possibly more sophisticated) on the pages of a document (either on every page, on the first page, or ***on selected pages***)

But I seem not be able to find the means to do that. What command should I use to apply watermark to say the 6th page only?

Comment: Would you be willing to switch from `draftwatermark` to `draftmark`? With the latter package, you could easily use the following example to just get a watermark on page 6 only:  `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[draft, pages=6-6]{draftmark}
\draftmarksetup{mark=text}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}`

Comment: Good to know, is it better than drafts watermark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using `draftmark` instead of `draftwatermark`. Since you also mentioned "more sophisticated" watermarks, this package could also come in handy. A simple MWE could look like the following:

The `draftmark` package also offers the following options to control the placement of the water mark text: `allpages`, `firstpage`, `oddpages`, `evenpages` , `page=x` (with x=page number of a single page) and `pages=x-y` (with x= start and y= end of the page range).

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage[draft, page=6]{draftmark} 
\draftmarksetup{mark=text} 
\begin{document} 
\blinddocument 
\blinddocument 
\blinddocument 
\end{document}
```